# Need to send new request to gpt after jsf render

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, google-dfp

Here is my issue. I have a dynamic page that loads ads initially when the page loads. As the page is interacted with, the gpt targeting changes and I need to submit a new request to gpt with the new values. I cannot use googletag.pubads().refresh() as the request does not have the right targeting. I need for the ad request to request completely new ads as if it was loaded with the page.